# How to add a template to body in Meteor inside a package

Tags: package, meteor, handlebars.js

I have this template:

```
<template name="sample">
  <h1>Sample</h1>
</template>
```

Inside a Meteor app I can add this to body this way (as a partial):

```
{{> sample}}
```

It works. I've even tested to call Template.sample(); inside browser console and it works.

When I move this inside my package (i.e. a sample.html file inside my package folder) the template seems to disappear: I get `Template.sample() is not a function` whenever I call the function and I am not even able to render it as a partial.

I have a `package.js` with this code (and obviously the package is correctly loaded inside my app through `packages` file in `.meteor`):

```
Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.add_files(['sample.html', 'sample.js'], 'client');
});
```

Why this doesn't work?
**How can I append a (reactive) Template to body from my package?**

Answer (score 30):

Solved! Add this line:

```
api.use(['templating'], 'client');
```

Comment: one other issue here is that if you chose to put a large part of your app into a package, you need to be careful about load order. You have to load the templates first before any related JS/coffee files or you'll get a "Template doesn't exist" type error.

Comment: You should accept your own answer, so the question shows up as “solved” and is better ranked  :)

Answer (score 12):

it is also important to include the `html` file before the `js`

```
api.add_files("client/sampleTemplate.html", "client");
api.add_files("client/sampleTemplate.js", "client");
```

Comment: Correct, so the template JS file has access to the template defined in the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Include in file `packages.js` of package

before

```
api.use('meteor-platform');
api.use('ui');`
```

after
first ".html" files, after ".js" files

```
api.addFiles('filename.html','client');
api.addFiles('filename.js','client');`
```