# aldeed tabular doesn't recognise cell template

Tags: meteor

I use an all packages architecture in a meteor project.
the CompanyButtons template is undefined in TabularLevel , the console log displays undefined and no template is displayed in the actions cell.

```
 TabularTables = {};


Meteor.isClient &&  console.log(Template.companyButtons)

TabularTables.Companies = new Tabular.Table({
    name: "Companies",
    collection: Companies,
    columns: [
        {data: "name", title: "Name"},
        {data: "phone", title: "Phone"},
        {data: "cities", title: "City"},
        {title:"actions", width:"80%", tmpl: Meteor.isClient &&  Template.companyButtons
        }

    ]
});
```

the template is correctly added

```
  api.addFiles([
     "lib/client/templates/utility/companyButtons.html",
  ], "client");
```

my template is recognised in the browser when i call Template.companyButtons

Comment: don't you need at least some `data` in the `actions` column?

Comment: wait, this has nothing to do with tabular. Your template is just not defined!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a template to body in Meteor inside a package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430102/how-to-add-a-template-to-body-in-meteor-inside-a-package)

Comment: @ChristianFritz when calling the template in the browser it exists , but not at Tabular level , i wonder if i have to export a variable for Tabular to be able to get the template .

Comment: didn't you say the `console.log(Template.companyButtons)` in your code prints `undefined`?

Comment: i solved the probleme , the tabluar script was loading before the template , i solved it but adding templates  files  before tabluar script

Answer (score 0):

Your template should be loaded before Tabular definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,
I solved this problem, you need to check your import files order, first import your .js files and then import tabular file

```
import './orders';
import '../lib/orders-tabular';
```